# Why is only one GET value showing

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to retrieve the values entered in the form below to pass into a PHP file so I can add the values into the database. The problem is I am only getting one of the values to pass into the PHP page, the URL bar only shows one value which is `equipmentList` I am new to JavaScript and PHP but I am guessing the solution is relativly simple. I know the problem is not with my PHP file because right now for testing/learning purposes I am only using `echo` to print the value of the `$_GET` variables that appear in the URL bar. My code below:

```
       <form id="updateForm" action="formPage.php">
       <input type="text" id="jobDescription" style="display: none"/>

        <label id="equipRan" style="display: none">Equipment ran</label>
        <div id="drops">
       <div id="equipType">
        <select size="1" name="equipmentList" title="" id="equipmentList" style="display: none">
            <option value="">Select Machine</option>
            <option value="EX">Excavator</option>
            <option value="DZ">Dozer</option>
            <option value="SC">Scraper</option>
        </select>
    </div>

   <div class="unitDropDowns">
      <div class="EX">
        <select class="exUnitNumbers">
            <option value="">Unit number</option>
            <option value="01E">01E</option>
            <option value="2E">2E</option>
            <option value="4E">4E</option>
        </select>           
    </div>

        <div class="DZ">
            <select class="dzUnitNumbers">
                <option value="">Unit number</option>
                <option value="01D">01D</option>
                <option value="2D">2D</option>
                <option value="1D">1D</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="SC">
            <select class="scUnitNumbers">
                <option value="">Unit number</option>
                <option value="54C">54C</option>
                <option value="53C">53C</option>
                <option value="52C">52C</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" id="updateButton" onclick="dbQuery()" style="display: none">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

JavaScript Function:

```
var dbQuery = function(){
    var description = document.getElementById("jobDescription").value;
    var selectedEquip = document.getElementById("equipmentList");
    var selectedEquip1 = selectedEquip.options[selectedEquip.selectedIndex].text;
    var selectedVisibleValue = $(".unitDropDowns select:visible").val();
    document.getElementById("descriptionSummary").innerHTML = "<h3>Description</h3>" + "<p>" + description + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("equipmentRan").innerHTML = "<h3>Equipment Ran </h3>" + "<p>" + selectedEquip1 + "</p>" + "<h3>Unit Number</h3>" + "<p>" + selectedVisibleValue + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("equipmentRan").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("descriptionSummary").style.display = "block";
    document.forms["updateForm"].submit();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you left off the name of the remaining select lists.  Add a name field to those select lists and then you should be able to request those values as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only your equipmentList select has a name and id.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the value of an html element such as `input` or `select` to be included in request submitted by the form, these elements must have `name` attribute defined.

The purpose of your `dbQuery` function is not clear. Html that you construct there will at best quickly flash in front of the user and then will be replaced by the new page returned from the server.

Comment: The code in the dbQuery is not being used anymore I was just using it to display the variables submitted by the form on the same page for testing/learning, I just did not delete it prior to posting this.